# disable scrollview without locking the UI

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an app which contains (among other controls) a UIScrollview. 
At certain times I need to disable scrolling on the scrollview, but I don't want to use the

```
   scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

property. How can I handle this?

I tried to intercept the

```
    -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    { 
    if(mycondition) {
      return;
    }
```

and when my condition is valid the code hits the return, but the scroll still occurs.

Comment: " because it locks the UI" - what do you mean? It only locks the scrollview so that it doesn't scroll - isn't that what you want?

Comment: no it locks the touches on that scrollview, which I want, but to disable the scrolling conditionally.

Comment: touches on subviews still work, what touches are you trying to pick up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close try this:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{  
   if(mycondition)
      [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];    
}
```

This should stop the scrolling if mycondition is true.

Comment: cool fix dude, all I am doing is  [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I have a sorta clumsy way to do it which may or may not help you.

Your attempt to do something with **scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:** didn't work because the method is just giving you news, not asking for permission (returns void).

Instead, you can implement **scrollViewDidScroll:**, which also isn't asking permission, but in that method you can keep the scroll from happening by setting the **contentOffset** value so that the scrollview does not, in fact, move.  To make this work, you have to detect elsewhere that you don't want to scroll and save the **contentOffset** at that point.

```
    // Condition starts.  Save the content offset
    if (whatever) {
       lockedContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
    }
```

...

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (condition_for_which_i_dont_want_to_scroll) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = lockedContentOffset;
        NSLog(@"Reset content offset");
    }
}
```

The method **scrollViewDidScroll:** will get called several times for each attempt to scroll since the scrollView is still trying to scroll and has momentum.  In my test of this code, however, I didn't see any apparent scrolling.

Hope this helps.